# How can I get a taxonomy menu into the main menu AND a block?

Tags: blocks, commerce, taxonomy-terms

I've got a taxonomy menu of products in DCommerce which appears in the main menu, but I also need it to show up in the sidebar. I installed menu_blocks but that can only access the main menu that the product menu is within.. and if I make the product menu into it's own menu, I can't get it into the main menu. Can it show up twice??

Answer (score 1):

[Taxonomy menu block](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block) combines the idea of **Taxonomy menu** with the workings of **Menu block**:

This module does not make use of Drupal's menu system. Taxonomy menu first creates a menu which can then be displayed through a block, this module creates the block directly.

```
Make multiple menus per vocabulary.

"Split" the taxonomy into different menus. 

Make a menu out of a specific branch of your vocabulary only.

Follow the active trail, also for nodes coupled to a term with a term reference field.
```